# Scroll to the middle of selected text

Tags: javascript, scroll, position, getselection

I am currently getting the selected text on a webpage by using `window.getSelection()`. What i want to do is slowly let the webpage scroll down, so i would be able to read everything without touching the screen.

- I do not ordinarily want to scroll nPX every nS
- I want to scroll so that a certain line is at the top of the window (i need the exact position of a word).
- I want it to work without having to change the DOM

*So, basically i want some way to tell javascript to give me the position of the nth word of window.getSelection(). How would i do that?*